# Unable to Connect to iPad via AnyDesk After Update: "Session Rejected" Error

Tags: ios, ipad, remote-desktop

After updating AnyDesk on my iPad a few days ago (February 2024), I can't connect from my Macbook Pro computer to my iPad anymore.

I tried connecting (to my iPad) using other personal computers but none of them can connect anymore (they were connecting just fine before). Before the update, everything worked normally.

Whenever I try to connect, I receive this error message on my MacBook Pro's Anydesk:

"Session Rejected

The remote user has rejected your session request."

The version history on the iPad app mentions these changes

1. incoming sessions from not licensed clients are blocked
2. exchanged code signing certificate. The previous certificate will be invalidated soon

The iPad app's version is **7.1.1**. Version **7.1.0**, the previous one, worked perfectly fine.

**Edit:**

I have the latest version of AnyDesk installed on my Mac (8.0.0) and the latest version on my iPad (7.1.1). I can't get my MacBook to connect to the iPad (I get the "Session Rejected" error); however, the reverse is possible, i.e., I can connect from my iPad to my Mac. Moreover, inside the AnyDesk app on my Mac, a green light appears next to the address of my iPad which suggests that the MacBook sees the iPad!

Comment: Did you verify that the AnyDesk client on your Mac is fully compatible with the client on your iPad?

Comment: How do I do that? I forgot to mention that I'm using the free version which I suspect is the problem. I use AnyDesk to connect mainly windows PCs to my iPad, which I use when I teach because its convenient to take notes on an ipad

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version installed.  Also, try rebooting the Mac.

Comment: I have the latest version installed on my Mac (8.0.0) and the latest version on my iPad (7.1.1). I can't get my MacBook to connect to the iPad (I get the session rejected error) however the reverse in possible, i.e., I can connect from my iPad to my Mac!

Comment: You may need to check with AD support

Comment: I tried that but they only provide that option to paid users, so it seems like there is no solution to this problem currently

Comment: I'm also now showing the exact same error, and same scenario/parameters. I can connect to my MBP without issue, but when connecting to my iPad from my mabook, shows session rejected. iPadOS 17.4
Anydesk v7.1.1 MacOS Sonoma 14.4
Anydesk 8.0.0 I've tried when on different networks, and also from my home network, both on the same WIFI. I'd love to see a solution to this :-)